# Parent scope variables don't update in the view when child controllers modify them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The jsFiddle for this question can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hsw9F/1/

*JavaScript* (`console.log` debug information available in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hsw9F/1/))

```js
var app = angular.module('StackOverflow',[]);

function ParentController($scope) {
 $scope.parentCounter = 5;
}

function ChildController($scope) {
  $scope.childCounter = $scope.parentCounter;
  $scope.increaseCounters = function() {
    ++$scope.parentCounter;
    ++$scope.childCounter;
  };
}
```

In the example above I have a counter in the parent and the child controllers named `parentCounter` and `childCounter` respectively. I've also provided a function in the child controller named `increaseCounters()` that increases both counters by one.

Both of these counters are displayed on the page:

```html
<div ng-app="StackOverflow">
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">

    Parent Counter: {{parentCounter}}<br />

    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      Child Counter: {{childCounter}}<br />
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"
         ng-click="increaseCounters()">Increase Counters</a>
    </div><!-- END ChildController -->

  </div><!-- END ParentController -->
</div><!-- END StackOverflow app -->
```

The problem is that AngularJS doesn't seem to update the `{{parentCounter}}` on the page, and only updates the `{{childCounter}}` when the increase counters function is called. Is there anything I have overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++$scope.parentCounter;` creates a child scope property with name `parentCounter` that hides/shadows the parent scope property of the same name.

Add `console.log($scope);` to your increaseCounters() function to see it.

One workaround: `++$scope.$parent.parentCounter;`

The problem you are experiencing has to do with the way JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.  I suggest reading [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) -- it has some nice pictures explaining what happens when primitives are created in child scopes.

Comment: You're right - in this case using `$scope.$parent.parentCounter` makes it function properly - http://jsfiddle.net/Hsw9F/4/.

Comment: @Trevor, I added a link to my answer that should be helpful.

Comment: One drawback of using $scope.$parent.parentCounter is when you move the parent or place another controller in between, that it will break.

Comment: @asgoth, thanks, I was being lazy.  I should have mentioned all 3 alternatives (I added a comment to your answer about the 3rd way).

Answer (score 2):

Because the child controller gets a copy of the parent counter value. If you want to increase the parent controller counter value, you need to execute a function on the parent controller:

```
function ParentController($scope) {
 $scope.parentCounter = 5;

  $scope.increaseParent = function() {
     ++$scope.parentCounter;
  };
}

function ChildController($scope) {
  $scope.childCounter = $scope.parentCounter;
  $scope.increaseCounters = function() {
    console.log('-------------------------------------');
    console.log('parent before: ' + $scope.parentCounter);
    console.log('child before: ' + $scope.childCounter);
    $scope.increaseParent();
    ++$scope.childCounter;
    console.log('parent after: ' + $scope.parentCounter);
    console.log('child after: ' + $scope.childCounter);
  };
}
```

Comment: For completeness, there's one more alternative: use an object in the parent scope.  E.g., `$scope.someObj = { parentCounter: 5 }` then in increaseCounters(), `++$scope.someObj.parentCounter`.  Due to prototypal inheritance, when the child scope looks for $scope.someObj, it will find it in the parent, then modify the parentCounter property.  (This is also explained in the link I provided.)